# Need a way to get multiple files to variable that shows total path size

Tags: windows, powershell

Looking for a way to pull all .pst files from a user's computer and show total amount of size of all (either separately or combined). The following will show the "count" of the pst files found, not the size.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\users -Filter "*.pst" -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname

For($i=0; $i -lt $path.Measure; $i++){
[pscustomobject] @{
    PSTsFound = $pa`your text`th[$i]
    }
    (Get-Item -Path $path).Length/1MB
}
```

When I use the file directly like so,

```
(Get-Item -Path 'C:\users\user\Documents\Outlook Files\
file@file.com.pst').Length/1MB
```

It give correct data.

How do I have the variable save as something to be checked for total size (space) and not count?

Should I just @echo each $path found with the `.Length` switch with separate responses?

Comment: If you just want the total length/size: `(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\users -Filter "*.pst" -Recurse  |Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB`

Comment: Thank you, that helped!

I actually re-wrote the script to: 
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter "*.pst" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname

Foreach($file in $files){
    echo $file
    (Get-Item -Path $file).Length/1MB
}

Which is working. Just changed the For Loop I was using

Comment: Great to hear you solved it yourself! You should post an answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

I was originally using the wrong For loop. Re-wrote to find .ost files as well.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter "*.pst" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname

Foreach($file in $files){
    echo $file
    (Get-Item -Path $file).Length/1MB
}
$files1 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter "*.ost" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname

Foreach($file in $files1){
    echo $file
    (Get-Item -Path $file).Length/1MB
}
```